# How could I display the sum of quantity from the fact table FacturesAvoir for each requestNo from the table F_demande_Achat?

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008

How could I display the sum of quantity from the fact table FacturesAvoir for each requestNo from the table F_demande_Achat?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set up a dimension that includes the three "F_" tables, and then link that dimension to the Measure Group that uses FacturesAvoir as its source.